# Dynamic provider for singleton - Angular 7

Tags: angular, typescript, provider

I have an angular application which can display lists of videos or articles and video's details or article's details.

I got ContentListPage and ContentDetailsPage which are the same for videos or articles .

The only difference is located on services layer which basically get data from youtube or from worpress.

I would like to have only one generic service dynamically provided depending on current content type. 
I'm able to have dynamic provider but as I'm using factory provider, A new service instance is created each time a component is created.

My main attempt was based on [factory provider](https://angular.io/guide/dependency-injection-providers#factory-providers)

So I define what kind of service should be provided into the useFactory. 
This is working well but when I navigate from ContentListPage to ContentDetailsPage a new instance of the service is be created.

I know that this is due to the way I provide service

```
@Component({
  . . .
  providers: [contentServiceProvider]
})
```

But I can't find how to provide on another level without back side effect.

### content.service.provider.ts

```js
const contentServiceFactory = (http: HttpService, metaMediaService: MetaMediaService) => {

  let contentService;
  if (metaMediaService.currentMetaMedia.type === MetaMediaType.WORDPRESS) {
    contentService = new MediasService(http, metaMediaService);
  } else {
    contentService = new YoutubeService(http, metaMediaService);
  }
  return contentService;
};

export let contentServiceProvider = {
  provide: ContentService,
  useFactory: contentServiceFactory,
  deps: [HttpService, MetaMediaService]
};
```

```js
@Component({
  . . .
  providers: [contentServiceProvider]
})
export class ContentListPage implements OnInit {

  constructor(public mediasService: ContentService<IContent>) {
```

### content-details.page.ts

```js
@Component({
  . . .
  providers: [contentServiceProvider]
})
export class ContentDetailsPage implements OnInit {

  constructor(public contentService: ContentService<IContent>) { }
```

### content.service.ts

```js
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export abstract class ContentService<T extends IContent> {
  abstract getContentById(id: number): Observable<T>;
  abstract  getContents(): Observable<T[]>;
  abstract loadMore(): Observable<T[]>;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Asking to a friend some advice, we conclude on using injector:

```
const contentServiceFactory = (metaMediaService: MetaMediaService, injector: Injector) => {
  if (metaMediaService.currentMetaMedia.type === MetaMediaType.WORDPRESS) {
    return injector.get(MediasService);
  } else {
    return injector.get(YoutubeService);
  }
};

export let contentServiceProvider = {
  provide: ContentService,
  useFactory: contentServiceFactory,
  deps: [MetaMediaService, Injector]
};
```